# I want to check a if condition with a specific structure into a string but with variables after 1 know string

Tags: string, vba

I have a string (Ex: blaZ-34blalba -$'34 ZBG-1004 Zblablabla).
I know the string I need as the form Z$$-%%%%, with $ as string and % as integer, the length of the string will be 8 long too. 
I need to get this string apart. 
Here is the code I tried ( I saw % and $ should replace string and integer), but it don't seems to work.

Maybe I just don't know what to look for (I did not find any cleans solutions).

```
Sub test1()
    Dim comment As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim eureka As Integer
    Dim posOfZ As Integer

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    comment = Range("A1").Text
    posOfZ = InStr(comment, "Z")
    name = Mid(comment, posOfZ, 8)
    eureka = 1

    While eureka = 1
        If name <> "Z$$-%%%%" Then
            comment = Replace(comment, "Z", "", 1, 1)
            posOfZ = InStr(comment, "Z")
            name = Mid(comment, posOfZ, 8)
        Else
            eureka = 0
        End If
   Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... you'll need to create a function to determine if you have a valid character as in `funIsChar` (see below).  You can modify this function to include any special chars if needed.  You may even decide that numbers are ok too and then you don't even have to check for char validity since it's already a string.

Also, don't forget to test for a situation where your format is not found.  If you scan the whole string and that format doesn't exist, you'll need to exit the routine gracefully.  I put `msgbox`'s in the code to show where exception handling is needed.

Plus, it's best to check `IsNumeric` for each of the individual 4 chars that are supposed to be a number separately.  If you try to do them all at once in one statement, decimals will be considered valid.  (Of course, if decimals are allowed, you should consider condensing down to one statement.)

Also, also... I flipped the logic value of your `eureka` test.  Usually (in programming logic) testing for 0 means it's "false" and testing for 1 is "true".  So you want to loop while the value has not been found (meaning it's false) and escape from the loop when `eureka` becomes true (indicating you've found what you were looking for).  I also added a new boolean flag `booEscapeFlag` to help exit the loop if the format is not found.  (I'll leave it to you as an exercise if you'd like to change your `eureka` variable to a boolean as well.)

```
Sub test1()
    Dim comment As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim eureka As Integer
    Dim posOfZ As Integer
    Dim booEscapeFlag As Boolean  ' New boolean escape from the loop flag

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    comment = Range("A1").Text
    posOfZ = InStr(comment, "Z")
    If posOfZ > 0 Then    ' Test if Z was found, if not, jump to "Z not found" message
       name = Mid(comment, posOfZ, 8)

       eureka = 0             ' Now set to 0 to indicate it's not found yet
       booEscapeFlag = False  ' Set boolean flag to false

       While eureka = 0 And Not booEscapeFlag    ' added test for not escaping yet
          If funIsChar(Mid(name, 2, 1)) Then     ' "Z$$-%%%%"
             If funIsChar(Mid(name, 3, 1)) Then
                If Mid(name, 4, 1) = "-" Then
                   If IsNumeric(Mid(name, 5, 1)) Then
                      If IsNumeric(Mid(name, 6, 1)) Then
                         If IsNumeric(Mid(name, 7, 1)) Then
                            If IsNumeric(Mid(name, 8, 1)) Then
                               eureka = 1
                            End If
                         End If
                      End If
                   End If
                End If
             End If
          End If

          If eureka <> 1 Then
              comment = Replace(comment, "Z", "", 1, 1)
              posOfZ = InStr(comment, "Z")
                  If posOfZ > 0 Then           ' Test to see if next Z was found
                     name = Mid(comment, posOfZ, 8)
                  Else
                     MsgBox "Z$$-%%%% format not found"
                     booEscapeFlag = True      ' Set boolean flag to true so we can exit the loop
                  End If
          End If
       Wend

       If eureka = 1 Then
          MsgBox "Found it: " & name
       End If

    Else
       MsgBox "Z not found"  ' This msg box was triggered by the first if statement at the top of the subroutine
    End If

End Sub

Function funIsChar(strChr) As Boolean
    Select Case Asc(strChr)
        Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122   ' Ascii 65 - 90 is uppercase letters, 97 - 122 is lowercase letters.  You can add more case statements if you need to test for special characters
            funIsChar = True
        Case Else
            funIsChar = False
    End Select
End Function
```

Hope that helps :)